# SiteMinder and HTTP Client - User Login Info

Tags: httpclient, siteminder

We have a Portlet running on Java/J2EE technology. It interacts with another application/system through HTTP request that requires user authentication. The current solution retrieves logged in user's user name and password from the Portal, and passes this information to back end systems using "HTTPClient" API's to retrieve content based on user's authentication and authorization.

There are efforts to enable site minder for the Portal. With site minder enablement, the Portal no longer provides logged in user's user name and password. The ideal way would be that back end application also has site minder enabled so that Portlet could pass the login token or cookie value.

Looking for interim approaches until the back end application is SiteMinder enabled. Is there a way we can enable/force user to enter user name and password ? I cannot think of such possibility because the Portlet code (using HTTP Client accesses the back end URL of the application, its not the browser). One possible way I can think of is, develop a new screen(UI) to have user enter user name and password within the Portlet and use that to authenticate with back end system through Java code. Please let me know if any other ideas.

Also, let me know if the question is confusing, I will provide more details.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Siteminder can provide user information dynamically to connected applications in HTTP headers (uid, email address, etc.). This behaviour is configured on the Siteminder Policy Server. By default, the HTTP header SM_USER (or similar) contains the username of the authenticated user.

Then, you have to adapt your portlet code to fetch those headers from the request and feed it to the back-end application like you used to.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise the use of the SM_USER header for tracking users.  SM_USER contains the ID that was provided to the credential collector, and will change based on the type of authentication scheme used.

Example:
If you have an HTML forms based auth scheme that collects email address instead of UserID, the email address will be sent in the SM_USER header.  In the case of an X.509 auth scheme the SubjectDN from the certificate will be in the SM_USER header.

The better choice would be to use the SM_UNIVERSALID header as that will always contain the Universal ID attribute.  The Universal ID attribute is configured in the User Directory object (typically this is set to "uid").